# Python 3: What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: python

This is a stripped down version of my code.
When I try to execute it, I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "test.py", line 16, in  value = oss.get()
>   TypeError: get() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

```
import os

class OsyncStateSerial():
        """Reads and writes current state serial for local replica"""

        def __init__(self, oss_file):
                if os.path.exists(oss_file):
                        pass
        def ranget():
                return 1

        def ranset():
                return 0

oss = OsyncStateSerial("somefile")
value = oss.ranget()
print(value)
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: ...Well this happens when too tired to code :) Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the argument `self` in your class methods:

```
import os

class OsyncStateSerial():
        """Reads and writes current state serial for local replica"""

        def __init__(self, oss_file):
                if os.path.exists(oss_file):
                        pass
        def ranget(self):
                return 1

        def ranset(self):
                return 0

oss = OsyncStateSerial("somefile")
value = oss.ranget()
print(value)
```

**Output**

```
1
```